# Add IP range to Ubuntu 16.04 server

Tags: ubuntu, linux-networking, ip-address, ubuntu-16.04

I'm trying to add IP range to `eth0` interface on Ubuntu 16.04 server.
Following this [solution](https://serverfault.com/questions/748005/how-to-assign-multiple-public-ip-addresses) I've changed the configuration to this:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto eth0

iface eth0 inet static
        address 118.69.119.107
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 118.69.119.0
        broadcast 118.69.119.255
        gateway 118.69.119.254
        up /sbin/ip address add 65.70.173.128/25 dev eth0
        down /sbin/ip address delete 65.70.173.128 dev eth0
```

And I've got only `65.70.173.128` IP available. Is this issue somehow related with `netmask`?

Answer (score 0):

You need one `up` (& `down`) line per every IP. The `/25` corresponds to the `netmask 255.255.255.128`; it's not specifying an IP address range.

Comment: Let me try right now. I thought there is more elegant way to do this.

Comment: Typically a single server interface won't need more than a couple of IP addresses. This was more usual before SNI when you needed one IP per every TLS certificate, and I've also seen it commonly in "IRC shell" servers, where large amounts of IPv6 addresses are used for creating "vanity hosts".

Comment: On RH it was possible to define range START/STOP IPs like [this](http://www.ducea.com/2006/07/15/linux-tips-how-to-quickly-bind-a-range-of-ips-on-redhat-based-systems/).